# Scanpst.exe vs. Scanost.exe (MS Outlook 07)

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007, pst

My OST file is having problems and the error dialogue (v.2007) instructed me to open scanpst.exe. I see that there is also a scanost.exe. Is there any difference between the two programs? Will I break something by using scanpst on an OST?

Comment: See [this Server Fault question](http://serverfault.com/questions/20590/scanost-vs-scanpst)